# Azure Search CRUD Operations

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

How do you make Insert, Update, Delete and Select on a single document in Azure Search preferably using the .NET library.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Document CRUD operations are available on the `ISearchIndexClient.Documents` property. Use the `Get` or `GetAsync` method to retrieve a single document by key. Use the `Index` or `IndexAsync` method to upload, merge, or delete documents.

Note that you should try wherever possible to batch up document write operations. Uploading/merging/deleting a single document at a time is very inefficient, which is why `Index` takes an `IndexBatch` as a parameter. You can batch up to 1000 write operations at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In some scenarios batching is OK. But in others we need to reflect the change (such as when a product is out of stock and if you wanted to wait for batches of 1000 you could be waiting a week for other changes which would not be acceptable to show false availability for that period of time.). In real applications, ideal situations rarely exist.

Comment: If documents in your application change on the order of weeks, then the lack of batching is not a big concern. Batching is more important for search services that are under constant heavy indexing pressure.

Comment: I was responding to your first comment about batching not being practical in your scenario. You can always call the Index method in the SDK with a batch of size one, just don't expect great throughput if you do.